# How do I regain Access to my admin setting in MacOS? (sudo commands work)

Tags: macos, command-line, administrator, sudo, macos-bigsur

I recently changed my password, upgraded to Big Sur and enabled MDM, nad have run int to an issue of accessing Admin setting in the UI.

I still have sudo access to become **root** on the command line.

**However I can't unlock the lock in the admin UI.** <- The problem.

I was silly and did not make a second admin user.

Is there a way to update Admin access from the cli?

Is there a better stackextange for this?

Comment: I assume this means you do not have any access to the root user?  You can [edit] your question to clarify that point

Comment: @Ramhound I can run `sudo -s` and get access to root yes. (updated question, thanks)

Comment: If you have root can’t you create a new user or is that something Apple determined wasn’t necessary?

Comment: @Ramhound useradd is not a command on my mac. the mac Unix system and the Mac UI system have a wall between them.

Comment: It may depend on what Mac (T2 or older) & what OS (SIP etc), but see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac @Ramhound - there is generally no root access on Mac unless it was previously specifically enabled (which is rare) Root has no better access than sudo. Single User mode is about the closest you get to a unix-type root access.

Comment: @Ramhound
It was an SMC reset issue. thank for your time!

Comment: @Tetsujin.
It was an SMC reset issue. thank for your time!

Answer (score 1):

IT turns out that this is an upgrade to Big Sur on a macbook with an Intel Processor.

I had to reset my SMC. Note it took doing the below steps 3 times before I hit all the buttons just right.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Steps copy pasted as requested:

Notebook computers with the T2 chip

Before resetting the SMC, try these steps:

```
Shut down your Mac.
Press and hold the power button for 10 seconds, then release the button.
Wait a few seconds, then press the power button to turn on your Mac.
```

If the issue persists, follow these steps to reset the SMC:

```
Shut down your Mac.
On your built-in keyboard, press and hold all of the following keys. Your Mac might turn on.
    Control  on the left side of your keyboard
    Option (Alt)  on the left side of your keyboard
    Shift  on the right side of your keyboard
Keep holding all three keys for 7 seconds, then press and hold the power button as well. If your Mac is on, it will turn off as you hold the keys.
Keep holding all four keys for another 7 seconds, then release them.
Wait a few seconds, then press the power button to turn on your Mac.
```

Desktop computers with the T2 chip

```
Shut down your Mac, then unplug the power cord.
Wait 15 seconds, then plug the power cord back in.
Wait 5 seconds, then press the power button to turn on your Mac.
```

Reset the SMC on other computers

If your Mac doesn't have the Apple T2 Security Chip, follow these steps. If you need help, contact Apple Support.
Notebook computers with a nonremovable battery

This applies to MacBook Pro models introduced in mid-2009 through 2017, MacBook Air models introduced in 2017 or earlier, and all MacBook models except the MacBook (13-inch, Mid 2009).

```
Shut down your Mac.
On your built-in keyboard, press and hold all of these keys:
    Shift  on the left side of your keyboard
    Control  on the left side of your keyboard
    Option (Alt)  on the left side of your keyboard
While holding all three keys, press and hold the power button as well.
Notebook keyboard with all 4 keys pressed
Keep holding all four keys for 10 seconds.
Release all keys, then press the power button to turn on your Mac.
```

Comment: You should quote the relevant information (procedure) you did in the event the support article isn't accessible in the future.

Comment: @Ramhound the things I copy and paste for an up vote :p